# How to efficiently iterate a pandas DataFrame and increment a NumPy array on these values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

My pandas/numpy is rusty, and the code I have written feels inefficient.

I'm initializing a numpy array of zeros in Python3.x, length 1000. For my purpose, these are simply integers:

```
import numpy as np
array_of_zeros =  np.zeros((1000, ), )
```

I also have the following DataFrame (which is much smaller than my actual data)

```
import pandas as pd
dict1 = {'start' : [100, 200, 300], 'end':[400, 500, 600]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
print(df)
##
##    start     end
## 0    100     400
## 1    200     500
## 2    300     600
```

The DataFrame has two columns, `start` and `end`. These values represent a range of values, i.e. `start` will always be a smaller integer than `end`. Above, we see the first row has the range `100-400`, next is `200-500`, and then `300-600`.

My goal is to iterate through the pandas DataFrame row by row, and increment the numpy array `array_of_zeros` based on these index positions. So, if there is a row in the dataframe of `10` to `20`, I would like to increment the zero by +1 for the indices 10-20.

Here is the code which does what I would like:

```
import numpy as np
array_of_zeros =  np.zeros((1000, ), )

import pandas as pd
dict1 = {'start' : [100, 200, 300], 'end':[400, 500, 600]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
print(df)

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for i in range(int(row.start), int(row.end)+1):
        array_of_zeros[i]+=1
```

And it works!

```
print(array_of_zeros[15])
## output: 0.0
print(array_of_zeros[600])
## output: 1.0
print(array_of_zeros[400])
## output: 3.0
print(array_of_zeros[100])
## output: 1.0
print(array_of_zeros[200])
## output: 2.0
```

My questions: this is very clumsy code! I shouldn't be using so many for-loops with numpy arrays! This solution will be very inefficient if the input dataframe is quite large

Is there a more efficient (i.e. more numpy-based) method to avoid this for-loop?

```
for i in range(int(row.start), int(row.end)+1):
    array_of_zeros[i]+=1
```

Perhaps there is a pandas-oriented solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use NumPy array indexing to avoid the inner loop, i.e. `res[np.arange(A[i][0], A[i][1]+1)] += 1`, but this isn't efficient as it involves creating a new array and using advanced indexing.

Instead, you can use `numba`<sup>1</sup> to optimize your algorithm, exactly as it stands. The below example shows a massive performance improvement by moving performance-critical logic to JIT-compiled code.

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def jpp(A):
    res = np.zeros(1000)
    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(A[i][0], A[i][1]+1):
            res[j] += 1
    return res
```

Some benchmarking results:

```
# Python 3.6.0, NumPy 1.11.3

# check result the same
assert (jpp(df[['start', 'end']].values) == original(df)).all()
assert (pir(df) == original(df)).all()
assert (pir2(df) == original(df)).all()

# time results
df = pd.concat([df]*10000)

%timeit jpp(df[['start', 'end']].values)  # 64.6 µs per loop
%timeit original(df)                      # 8.25 s per loop
%timeit pir(df)                           # 208 ms per loop
%timeit pir2(df)                          # 1.43 s per loop
```

Code using for benchmarking:

```
def original(df):
    array_of_zeros = np.zeros(1000)
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        for i in range(int(row.start), int(row.end)+1):
            array_of_zeros[i]+=1   
    return array_of_zeros

def pir(df):
    return np.bincount(np.concatenate([np.arange(a, b + 1) for a, b in \
                       zip(df.start, df.end)]), minlength=1000)

def pir2(df):
    a = np.zeros((1000,), np.int64)
    for b, c in zip(df.start, df.end):
        np.add.at(a, np.arange(b, c + 1), 1)
    return a
```

---

<sup>1</sup> For posterity, I'm including @piRSquared's excellent comment on why `numba` helps here:

> `numba`'s advantage is looping very efficiently. Though it can
>   understand much of NumPy's API, it is often better to avoid creating
>   NumPy objects within a loop. My code is creating a NumPy array for
>   every row in the dataframe. Then concatenating them prior to using
>   bincount. @jpp's `numba` code creates very little extra objects and
>   utilizes much of what is already there. The difference between my
>   NumPy solution and @jpp's `numba` solution is about 4-5 times. Both are
>   linear and should be pretty quick.

Comment: You know I like `numba`.  Also `from numba import njit` -> `njit` is `jit(nopython=True)`

Comment: @piRSquared, Thanks! I hope you don't mind my adding timings from your solutions. Yeh, I know about `njit`, but I think sometimes it's more explicit for those new to `numba`.

Comment: Thanks! The jpp implementation is very impressive! My remaining question: Is it possible to optimize the @piRSquared code with `numba`?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang `numba`'s advantage is looping very efficiently.  Though it can understand much of Numpy's api, it is often better to avoid creating Numpy objects within a loop.  My code is creating a Numpy array for every row in the dataframe.  then concatenating them prior to using bincount.  @jpp's `numba` code creates very little extra objects and utilizes much of what is already there.  The difference between my Numpy solution and jpp's `numba` solution is about 4-5 times.  Both are linear and should be pretty quick.

Comment: Why have you used res[np.arange(A[i][0], A[i][1]+1)] += 1 (allocating a temporary array, filling it in a loop with values, using it to index array res within another loop)?  Is there a missleading tutorial which should be corrected? A simple nested loop is aprox. 2 times faster for quite obvious reasons (mentioned above). Nevertheless your timings are quite slow, even for this approach. Have you called the function once before using timeit? If not you measured a constant compilation overhead for the first time aprox. 0.2s, which could also be minimized with cache=True

Comment: @max9111, Good point, have updated. Unless I'm mistaken just moving the nested `for` loop into `numba` moves timing into microseconds (but that *could* be due to caching).

Comment: I got about 7ms, but there can be quite high differences on measuring tiny memory bound functions, which works on arrays which fits entirely in cache. According Numba (nopython mode): It does quite the same like Clang (C,C++) or Flang (Fortran), but for Python Code. (All of them translate the code to LLVM-IR and use LLVM to compile it to machine dependend assembler afterwards). So it is clearly recommendable to write the code like you would in C or Fortran.

Answer (score 4):

#### `numpy.bincount`

```
np.bincount(np.concatenate(
    [np.arange(a, b + 1) for a, b in zip(df.start, df.end)]
), minlength=1000)
```

---

#### `numpy.add.at`

```
a = np.zeros((1000,), np.int64)
for b, c in zip(df.start, df.end):
  np.add.at(a, np.arange(b, c + 1), 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution

```
for x, y in zip(df.start, df.end):
    array_of_zeros[x:y+1]+=1
```

Comment: `array_of_zeros[x:y] += 1`?

Comment: @piRSquared I try it before , seems not work .. let me test it again

Comment: should you not include the `y` also? ie  `x:y` excludes `y`, should it not be `x:(y+1)`??

Comment: @Onyambu hi double ?? fixed :-)

Comment: using loop is the way to do that sure. But it is not efficient it takes a lot more time. see this blog post for about analysis of different methods of iterating DataFrame and their efficiency and estimate of time. https://towardsdatascience.com/apply-function-to-pandas-dataframe-rows-76df74165ee4